# how to send an object from spring controller to jsp through Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a transaction object and I am trying to send the object to the front page. I have no problem when I try to send a string, but I couldn't send an object.

So this is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/result/helloajax", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public MyTransaction helloahjax() {
        System.out.println("hello Ajax");
        MyTransaction tran = MyTransaction.getInstance();
        tran.setId(123);
        return tran;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show() {
        return "result";
    }
```

and this is my ajax call

```
<a href="#" onclick="doajax()">button</a>
<div class="result"></div>


function doajax() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/result/helloajax',
        success : function(response) {
            $('.result').html(response.id);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("asda");
        }
    });
};
```

I search around and see that other developers used "response.result.id" but I couldn't make it neither. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change your code like below.

1.Include JSON library to your classpath and add `produces="application/json"` attribute to RequestMapping for the helloahjax method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result/helloajax", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
```

2.Include dataType in your ajax call,like below

```
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/result/helloajax',
        success : function(response) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
              //Now you can set data as you want
              $('.result').html(obj.id);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("asda");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL would change to below when you are returning JSON from the controller method. In this case you don't need to parse the response. Instead you can directly access the object variables as response.abc

${pageContext.request.contextPath}/result/helloajax.json